# In a package: ORA-00942 table or view does not exist

Tags: oracle, plsql, datatable, package, oracle-sqldeveloper

So, I think I've scoured all the similar posts and can't solve mine.

In a pkg spec, I declared:

```
TYPE record_type IS RECORD (Pat_Nbr VARCHAR2(4),
  Trt_Procedure VARCHAR2(5),
  Phys_ID VARCHAR2(3),
  Phys_Name VARCHAR2(20),
  Phys_Specialty VARCHAR2(18));
TYPE table_type IS TABLE OF record_type INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
t_Pat_Trt table_type;
PROCEDURE BuildPatTbl
  (t_PatTrt OUT table_type,
  PatTblCount IN OUT NUMBER);
```

In the body, I wanted to do a simple SELECT INTO with a join. Didn't work so I've tried all of these (note 3 tries - the last two commented out), and I still get the 00942 error.

```
PROCEDURE BuildPatTbl
  (t_PatTrt OUT table_type,
  PatTblCount IN OUT NUMBER)
IS
   CURSOR cur_tbl IS SELECT a.Pat_Nbr, a.Trt_Procedure, Phys_ID, b.Phys_Name, b.Phys_Specialty
                      FROM Treatment a INNER JOIN Physician b
                      USING (Phys_ID);
    temp_rec record_type;
BEGIN
  OPEN cur_tbl;
  LOOP 
    FETCH cur_tbl into temp_rec;
    EXIT WHEN cur_tbl %NOTFOUND;
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO t_PatTrt VALUES (temp_rec);
    END;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur_tbl;
  /*EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE t_PatTrt 
  (Pat_Nbr VARCHAR2(4),
    Trt_Procedure VARCHAR2(5),
    Phys_ID VARCHAR2(3),
    Phys_Name VARCHAR2(20),
    Phys_Specialty VARCHAR2(18)))';*/
  /*FOR t_Pat_record IN cur_tbl LOOP
    INSERT INTO t_PatTrt VALUES t_Pat_record;
  END LOOP;*/
END BuildPatTbl;
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: Does you package schema has select privileges on Treatment and Physician tables. Did you try a simple select * from Treatment or Physician? Is you package in the same schema as mentioned tables?

Comment: Yes, all same schema and I have privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to treat a collection as a database table. That isn't ever going to fly - they're two totally different things.

Why are you wanting to select records into your array? What are you ultimately going to do with the results? If you're going to loop through and do some other DML based on the information, you will be better off doing the whole thing in a single SQL statement.

If you absolutely must store the results in a collection, look into [bulk collect](http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/bulk-binds-and-record-processing-9i.php)

Comment: So, I was told to build a table. I do get confused with collections - seems like a TABLE or RECORD should be a table, but no?

Comment: A database table is a permanent object, stored in the database's dictionary table. It is allocated space on disk to store rows that may be inserted. A table type may or may not be defined as a permanent object (you can define it in PL/SQL only, or at the database level), but it is a *type* - in other words, it defines the structure of whichever variable or column is assigned as that type. When you define a variable as a table type, it's still only a variable. A variable != a database table!

Comment: You'll need to update your question with more details on what it is you're trying to achieve (and why - is this some sort of homework question?) - it's entirely possible that you're going about your objective in the wrong way, but we can't tell that from your original question.

Comment: So, I was told to build a table. I do get confused with collections - seems like a TABLE or RECORD should be a table, but no?

A single SQL statement like I had in the cursor? 
SELECT a.Pat_Nbr, a.Trt_Procedure, Phys_ID, b.Phys_Name, b.Phys_Specialty
                      BULK COLLECT INTO t_PatTrt.Pat_Nbr, t_PatTrt.Trt_Procedure, t_PatTrt.Phys_ID, t_PatTrt.Phys_Name, t_PatTrt.Phys_Specialty
                      FROM Treatment a INNER JOIN Physician b
                      USING (Phys_ID); 

error  00302 PAT_NBR must be declared.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, direct insert is not possible in collections, you can use bulk collect into feature to achieve this

```
OPEN cur_tbl;
    FETCH cur_tbl bulk collect into t_Pat_Trt;

CLOSE cur_tbl;
```